# HttpWebRequest.StatusCode 200 "OK", but application not getting updated

Tags: wcf

I'm executing the following code

```
string requestUrl = "http://SFPRTH010001:18109/1010-SF-TNTIN/Configurator/rest/importConfiguration?";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
//request.ContentType = "application/json";

byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes("TestSCDS.properties");
request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;
MessageBox.Show(fileToSend.Length.ToString());

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
    //MessageBox.Show(requestStream.);
    requestStream.Close();
}

using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
    MessageBox.Show(resp.StatusCode.ToString());                    
}
```

I'm getting HTTP Status code "OK" and Fiddler also displays status 200. After running these services, I'm expecting some keys to be updated, which is not happening. Can anybody please let me know what the issue might be?

Comment: You're not providing enough details. What does the service code look like? Where are you executing this client code? Have you tried debugging the service yet, is the code even hit? What do your server logs tell you about the request?

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting WCF service? If yes, I'd suggest you to enable WCF tracing for the service which will confirm if there's any exception occurred in service, which seems to be then handled. You can use following trace configuration,

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

HTH,
Amit